# Parametrizing curve for complex analysis integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that

$$
\int_{|z-z_0| = R} (z-z_0)^m \, dz = \begin{cases}0, & m \neq -1 \\ 2\pi i, & m =- 1. \end{cases}
$$

Here's my attempt at a solution:

We parametrize the curve at $z(\theta) = z_0 + Re^{i\theta}$ and therefore $dz = iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta$. Substituting, we have

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} R^me^{im\theta} \, iRe^{i\theta} \, d\theta.
$$

However, I feel that this is wrong since there will be a dependence on $R$. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: It equales $2\pi i$ if $m=-1$.

Comment: Try doing the rest of that integral in the $m\neq -1$ case first. Does $R$ really matter?

Comment: My bad, fixed it.

Comment: Your piecewise is still mixed up. $m=-1$ is the $2\pi i$ case, $m\neq -1$ is the 0 case.

Comment: You need to deform your contour. See [this](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews//c2003/cauchygoursat/CauchyGoursatTheorem.3.pdf). You can consider the contour $C:|z-z_0|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, your work is correct. Factoring out constants, you simply need to evaluate

$$i R^{m + 1} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(m + 1) \theta} d\theta$$

Now if $m = -1$, then $R$ has exponent $0$ and will simply become $1$; if $m \ne -1$, then the integral vanishes and kills the dependence on $R$ anyways.

Comment: How does the integral vanish if $m \neq -1$? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: Compute the integral explicitly; you might find it helpful to write the real and imaginary parts out separately. Also, you should fix the piecewise definition in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cauchy integral formula

$\int_{|z-z_0| = R} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz=2\pi i\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$

For $m=-1$, if we choose $f(z)=1$, then by cauchy integral formula

$\int_{|z-z_0| = R} (z-z_0)^{-1}dz =2\pi i$

For $m\in\{-2,-3,-4,....\}$

Take $f(z)=1$

Then by cauchy integral formula we have

$\int_{|z-z_0| = R} (z-z_0)^{m}dz=2\pi i\frac{f^{(-m-1)}(z_0)}{(-m-1)!}=0\hspace{0.02cm} $$\hspace{0.02cm}$because derivatives of constant function are zero.

For $\hspace{0.05cm}m\in\{0,1,2,3,4,......\}$ $\hspace{0.02cm}$ you can use Cauchy Goursat Theorem to prove that

$\int_{|z-z_0| = R} (z-z_0)^{m}dz=0$

So in general

$$
\int_{|z-z_0| = R} (z-z_0)^m \, dz = \begin{cases}0, & m \neq -1 \\ 2\pi i, & m = -1. \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $m\geqslant 0, f(z) = (z - z_{0})^{m}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.  Thus the line integral is 0 ( by FTOC ).

For $m = -1, f(z) = 1$ is analytic on the closed disc $\rvert z - z_{0}\rvert\leqslant R$, so by Cauchy's integral formula this implies that $$1 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\rvert z - z_{0}\rvert = R}\frac{1}{z - z_{0}}\,\mathrm{d}z.$$  Therefore the integral is $2\pi$.

For $m < -1$, take the derivative.. so $$0 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\rvert z - z_{0}\rvert = R}(z - z_{0})^{m}\,\mathrm{d}z$$.